# Can Vue.js custom directive be implemented as individual files?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there any way that Vue custom directives can be implemented as individual files (ala Vue components .vue file) and be compiled in the root js file? (I'm using Webpack)

I tried the following on app.js but it's not recognised.

```
require('./directives/test.js');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell me what do you want to do? Is the final result <my-custom-directive></my-custom-directive> somewhere in html?

Answer (score 11):

A directive is only a class with a few well-defined methods. In JS, you can write something like :

```
export const MyDirective {
    bind(el,binding,vnode) {
        /* your code */
    }
}
```

then, in the file where you use it :

```
<template>
    <p v-app-my-directive:arg.modifier="value">Some Text</p>
</template>
<script>
    import MyDirective from './directives/MyDirective.js';

    export default {
        directives: {
            AppMyDirective: MyDirective
        }
        /* ... */
    }
</script>
```

You can also use

```
Vue.directive('app-my-directive', MyDirective)
```

to declare it globally.

Comment: You may also use `directives: {MyDirective}` instad of `directives: {AppMyDirective: MyDirective}` if your directive name can be the same as the file name. I always go for the shorter version.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a global directives file similar to how the global filters are created.

```
Create a directives.js

import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.directive('purple', function(el) {
    el.style.color = 'purple'
})

Import it into your main.js
```

Refer: [How to add a bunch of global filters in Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47004702/how-to-add-a-bunch-of-global-filters-in-vue-js)

Comment: This does not work. The example in the end in this blog works. https://labs.thisdot.co/blog/custom-directives-in-vue-js

Answer (score 2):

I created a directory at /js/directives and added a file called AutoFocus.js with the following contents:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

const AutoFocus = {
  inserted(el) {
    el.focus();
  },
};

export default {
  AutoFocus,
};

// Make it available globally.
Vue.directive('focus', AutoFocus);
```

Note that, instead of 'inserted' above you may need to try 'bind' or 'update' depending on the approrpiate hook function for your scenario. I just replaced and tested with each until one worked!
Then in my component i use the directive as follows:

```
<template>
    <input type="text" v-focus />
</template>
<script>
    import AutoFocus from '../../../directives/AutoFocus'; // Must point to your file!
    export default {
        directives: {
            AutoFocus,
        },
        // ... your other code here, eg props/methods etc
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I'm using Vue with Laravel and I'll give you what works for me.

In your app.js ( root file ) register components ( or directives ) as global Vue components.

So:
    // import Vue

```
Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('my-custom-component', require('./directives/ComponentFileName.vue')
```

After this you'll be able to use it in html like so:

```
<my-custom-component></my-custom-component>
```

I'm sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I know it works for components. But, it couldn't seem to work for directives. However, strangely, it's working now. Thanks for your feedback anyway.