# How to add a bunch of global filters in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to make use of a few global filters in a Vue.js app. I know I need to define them before my main Vue instance, but sticking them all in the 'main.js' file doesn't seem right to me from a code organisation point of view. How could I have the definitions in a separate file, imported to 'main.js'? Can't quite get my head around the import/export stuff for this.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Create a filters.js file.

```
import Vue from "vue"

Vue.filter("first4Chars", str => str.substring(0, 4))
Vue.filter("last4Chars", str => str.substring(str.length - 4))
```

Import it into your main.js.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import "./filters"

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
})
```

Here is a working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mqwv333zr8).

**Side note:** If you get a "Vue not found" type of error, as a test try importing filters *after* the `new Vue()` declaration, like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
})

import "./filters"
```

Comment: As simple as that! Thanks.

Comment: when I named the file `filter.js` I had to use `import "./filter"`

Comment: good answer, for better reading I make a folder called `filter` and write the filter in a file `filter/index.js` than you can import `./filters`.

Answer (score 41):

I think the best way is to use the `plugin`feature from VueJS

1. Create a `filters` folder and put all of you filters there ...

   ```
   - filters
     | - filter1.js
     | - index.js
   ```
2. In the filter file export the function you need, in this example I'll use a uppercase filter:

   ```
   export default function uppercase (input) {
       return input.toUpperCase();
   }
   ```
3. In the `index.js` import and create a plugin:

   ```
   import uppercase from './filter1';


   export default {
        install(Vue) {
            Vue.filter('uppercase', uppercase);
        }
   }
   ```
4. In you **main.js** file use it

   ```
   import filters from './filters';
   import Vue from 'vue';

   Vue.use(filters);
   ```

Comment: this feels more neatly contained than calling `Vue.filter(...)` in each filter definition file

Comment: I had trouble getting this to work with my application and realized that Vue evaluates conditional expressions differently in the HTML template than Angular does. Proper syntax for this would be `{{ value ? $options.filters.uppercase(value, 'params) : '--' }}`

Answer (score 7):

What I like to do is

1. Have a filter per file (es6 module)
2. Register the filter globally with vue in the module
3. Also export the filter function as the default export

For example for a simple filter that puts comma separators in numbers I create NumberFilter.js and NumberFilter.test.js

*NumberFilter.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import numeral from 'numeral';

const NumberFilter = number => numeral(value).format('0,0');

Vue.filter('number', numberFilter);

export default numberFilter;
```

*NumberFilter.test.js*

```
import NumberFilter from './NumberFilter';

describe('NumberFitler', () => {
   it('exists', () => {
      expect(NumberFilter).toBeDefined();
   });

   it('does its thing', () => {
       expect(NumberFilter(1234)).toEquals('1,234');   
   });
});
```

This strategy allows me to use this filter in code as a standard es6 module and as well as in my Vue templates.

In the real world I would probably mock numeral in my test and just make sure the result of .format was called with the correct number format.

Answer (score 7):

**[Vue mixins][1]** could be used to add global filters, filters can setup in a file and then import filters file in **main.js** file.

### filters.js

```
export default{
    firstWordCapitalize (value) => {
        if (!value)
            return ''
        value = value.toString()
        return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    },
    anotherFilter(value) =>{
      return value+"-test";
    }
}
```

### main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Filters from './filters';
Vue.mixin({
  filters: Filters
});
```

And you can use filters in any template.
[1]: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Comment: VueJS official docs warn against overusing global mixins because they get injected into EVERY instance of Vue that gets created.